# Reason for ubi filesystem corruption

Tags: linux, filesystems, flash-memory, ubifs

I have used ubi filesystem and mtd subsystem to work on the top of NAND flash.
It was working fine.

But now I'm finding the following errors:

UBI error: ubi_io_read: error -74 while reading 516096 bytes from PEB 2701:8192, read 516096 bytes

end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock5, sector 49160

what is the reason for those errors which I have mentioned above?
How to recover from these error?

Comment: These messages by themselves do not indicate an issue.  If you have the Linux source, you can compile the *drivers/mtd/test* modules and run them on your device.  These test should indicated if there is some software issue with your hardware combination (flash chip + flash controller).  **Note:** some of the tests are destructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both shows I/O errors which is related to corruption or bad block on your NAND Flash, try using another flash and use it. You can also try erasing flash and trying it again.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: what are the precautions has to be taken to avoid NAND flash corruption?

Comment: Hi NAND flash corruption can happen due to many factors no proper mounts or multiple read/writes etc.

Answer (score 4):

Error -74 is `EBADMSG`.  Looking at [*ubi.h*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/ubi/ubi.h#n94) we can see,

- **UBI_IO_FF**: the read region of flash contains only 0xFFs
- **UBI_IO_FF_BITFLIPS**: the same as %UBI_IO_FF, but also also there was a data
                    integrity error reported by the MTD driver
                    (uncorrectable ECC error in case of NAND)
- **UBI_IO_BAD_HDR**: the EC or VID header is corrupted (bad magic or CRC)
- **UBI_IO_BAD_HDR_EBADMSG**: the same as %UBI_IO_BAD_HDR, but also there was a
                        data integrity error reported by the MTD driver
                        (uncorrectable ECC error in case of NAND)
- **UBI_IO_BITFLIPS**: bit-flips were detected and corrected

Each UBI block is a flash erase block (typical 128K) and these blocks have two UBI headers which are a pages size (typical 2k).  When this page was read, there was an error.  Which was not recoverable via the *error correcting codes* or ECC.

If you are using *UBI* on top of *UbiFs*, these blocks should be scheduled to be *tortured*.  This involves erasing and re-writing the erase block.  Flash can go *stale* if it is read many times.  The bits can flip and require that the data be re-written.  It may turn out that the *UBI* header just needs to be re-programmed and the flash will be fine.

If not, all NAND *mtd* drivers have a [bad block table](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/nand-data/nanddata.html).  In the case the data is really not recoverable, the erase block will be marked bad in this table and *Ubi* should no longer use this sector.

If the error persists then this is a possible issue.  However, it is somewhat expected with normal use of NAND flash.  Typical cycles are 1,000 to 100,000 for NAND flash.  After a certain amount of wear it is possible that the flash can be totally unusable.  This depends on the flash type, the file system (and [wear leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling)), and the applications on the system.

A mis-configured flash driver can cause these errors.  Improper ECC code for the flash can cause pre-mature errors (flash provides space for 4bit ECC, but driver only implements 1bit for instance).  It can also be caused by a bad application that constantly `fsync()` the disk every 1ms-100ms; this type of behavior will wear the flash in a few years even with all of the other components being optimal.  *Ubi* should have some of the best wear leveling
available.  If you constantly *re-flash* an image, you can discount the *ubi* wear leveling and cause this kind of issue.

Comment: I think your posted error log is not complete.  See [io.c, ubi_io_read()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/ubi/io.c?#n185), as it has a retry count for the message you posted (at least with current mainline).  So this message should have occurred multiple times.