# Can't run make flash, getting error "fatal error: /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h: Bad message"

Tags: linux, makefile, raspberry-pi4

I have a raspberry pi running Klipper (specifically MainsailOS), and I'm trying to use the instructions [here](https://github.com/Klipper3d/klipper/blob/master/docs/RPi_microcontroller.md) to setup the pi as a secondary mcu, to use an ADXL sensor for input shaping.

Following those steps, I get all the way to `make flash`, before getting the following output. Note, I've also tried running with sudo.

```
pi@mainsail:~/klipper $ make flash
  Creating symbolic link out/board
  Building out/autoconf.h
  Compiling out/src/sched.o
  Compiling out/src/command.o
  Compiling out/src/basecmd.o
  Compiling out/src/debugcmds.o
  Compiling out/src/initial_pins.o
  Compiling out/src/gpiocmds.o
  Compiling out/src/stepper.o
  Compiling out/src/endstop.o
  Compiling out/src/trsync.o
  Compiling out/src/adccmds.o
  Compiling out/src/spicmds.o
  Compiling out/src/i2ccmds.o
  Compiling out/src/pwmcmds.o
  Compiling out/src/buttons.o
  Compiling out/src/tmcuart.o
  Compiling out/src/neopixel.o
  Compiling out/src/pulse_counter.o
  Compiling out/src/lcd_st7920.o
  Compiling out/src/lcd_hd44780.o
  Compiling out/src/spi_software.o
  Compiling out/src/i2c_software.o
  Compiling out/src/sensor_lis2dw.o
  Compiling out/src/thermocouple.o
  Compiling out/src/sensor_adxl345.o
  Compiling out/src/sensor_angle.o
  Compiling out/src/sensor_mpu9250.o
  Compiling out/src/linux/main.o
  Compiling out/src/linux/timer.o
  Compiling out/src/linux/console.o
In file included from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/ioctls.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/ioctl.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/pty.h:28,
                 from src/linux/console.c:11:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/ioctls.h:7:10: fatal error: /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h: Bad message
    7 | #include <asm-generic/ioctls.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:64: out/src/linux/console.o] Error 1
pi@mainsail:~/klipper $
```

I know enough about Linux to get by, but errors like this seem out of my league. It seems like maybe that file isn't where it's expected but I don't know.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65285028/1216776

Comment: @stark I came across that, but this error, while the same message, seems to point to what look to be system files, whereas that looks like it was just the project files. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I just don't see a solution there.

Comment: The I/O routines neither know nor care whether you are opening system or project files. The error means the underlying filesystem is broken. Wipe it and start over.

Comment: Is there a way I can test that the filesystem is broken? "wipe computer" seems like a pretty harsh resolution, at least without being able to verify, considering everything else works and the amount of setup that was required to get to this point.